# How to group filtered rows against non filtered by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to generate a report for accepted orders each month against the total orders for that month. For example, I have a table `Orders` like so:

```
Order_Id    Submit_Date    Order_Status
--------    -----------    ------------
1           20130501       Accepted
2           20130509       Rejected
3           20130610       Accepted
4           20130614       Accepted
5           20130626       Rejected
6           20130802       Accepted
7           20130801       Accepted
8           20131014       Accepted
9           20140116       Rejected
10          20140121       Rejected
```

And would like to get the results like so:

```
[Month]    Accepted    Total
-------    --------    -----
2013-05    1           2
2013-06    2           3
2013-08    2           2
2013-10    1           1
2014-01    2           2
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: No, it is in the usual DATATIME type in the database. I just simplified it here to avoid confusion. The usual SQL DATATIME functions will work on it. And those are just words that I came up with. Order is Order_ID, Date is Submitted_Date.

Comment: That doesn't avoid confusion at all.

Comment: So let me get this straight you came on SO to ask a technical question from other expert developers and thought they might be confused by the `datetime` datatype. Just for future notice do not do this. Post your data as it it will be most helpful that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will never have a time component, this should work just fine:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE([Order] INT, [Date] DATETIME, [Status] CHAR(8));

INSERT @d VALUES
(1 ,'20130501','Accepted'),
(2 ,'20130509','Rejected'),
(3 ,'20130610','Accepted'),
(4 ,'20130614','Accepted'),
(5 ,'20130626','Rejected'),
(6 ,'20130802','Accepted'),
(7 ,'20130801','Accepted'),
(8 ,'20131014','Accepted'),
(9 ,'20140116','Rejected'),
(10,'20140121','Rejected');

SELECT 
  [Month] = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY([Date]), [Date]),
  Accepted = SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  COUNT(*)
FROM @d
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY([Date]), [Date])
ORDER BY [Month];
```

(And if you are on SQL Server 2008 or newer, you should use the `DATE` data type to prevent having to deal with any errant hours/minutes.)

If you can have hours/minutes sometimes, and you're not on 2008 or greater, then:

```
SELECT 
  [Month] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0),
  Accepted = SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  COUNT(*)
FROM @d
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)
ORDER BY [Month];
```

I strongly recommend avoiding any solutions that group by using string conversions. Date/time math is much more efficient in SQL Server than converting to strings. Also if you want the client side to present things like `2013-05`, use Format(), ToString() etc. to apply that string formatting on the client.

Answer (score 1):

To get yyyy-dd format you can use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[Date],20)
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'Accepted' THEN 1
               ELSE NULL END) AS 'Accepted'
   ,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[Date],20)
```

Comment: Output will be `2013-5`, not `2013-05` as OP requested. Also please [don't convert to varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). You have two `END` declarations inside your case. And when I fix that, I get "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1 -  Column '@d.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I think this is one of those cases where you tried to get your answer in so quickly, you didn't test it.

Comment: I was in process of modifying my answer at same time as your comment. second query will produce results requested by OP

Comment: You should remove the first code snippet because it is wrong in many ways. Also a much cheaper (relatively) way of your substring is `CONVERT(CHAR(7), [Date], 120)`. I still don't believe you should be using SQL Server to convert that to a string, and group by, just to get that presentation. As I said in my answer, date math is much more efficient.

Comment: When I have done both queries against table with 50k rows it came back with 48% to 52% execution cost. Your query won. I would say that is minimal difference when dealing with small tables. Even with that it took less than 1 second to execute both queries with each one having 2k results.

Comment: Don't look at those percentages, they're garbage. Execute the query 50,000 times and measure the duration and CPU usage throughout. Converting to string is higher CPU and, at scale, should take longer. When you execute them once and only look at meaningless cost %s that have little to no insight into scalar operators, you're bound to make the wrong decision.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(Date)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(Date)) Period, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0) Accepted,
    COUNT(*) Total

FROM Orders
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
ORDER BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: This will have output like `2013/5` instead of `2013-05` as OP requested. Also, your `WHERE` clause completely eliminates January, and leads to inaccurate totals in most other months.

Comment: My distraction. Thank you.